# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression using Stored Procedure

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, asp-classic, vbscript, syntax-error

I am basically getting this error when trying to run a stored procedure from with a classic asp page, and I cannot see where the problem is lying.

the error from my log files is

```
72|80040e14|Syntax_error_(missing_operator)_in_query_expression_'1_'17470329'_#30/10/2012#_94'
```

the code at line 72 is the following

```
rs.open "UpdateTransaction 1 '" & Request.Form("TXID") & "' #" & String2Date & "# " & Request.Form("pageID"), conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdStoredProc
```

a string generated version of line 72 is :

`UpdateTransaction 1 '17470312' #30/10/2012# 93`

The stored procedure within Access is

```
UPDATE [TRANSACTIONS] SET Status = [param1], TransactionID = [param2], TransactionDate = [param3]
WHERE pageID = [param4];
```

The structure of the table is as follows

```
Status : Number
TransactionID : Text
TransactionDate : Date
pageID : Number
```

from what I can see, I have the parameters and types correct, but I just can't see the problem from looking too hard!

Comment: not much familier with vb6 but isn't string should be  UpdateTransaction 1, '17470312', #30/10/2012#, 93

Comment: I would not insert dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy into MS Access. As soon as the day falls below 13, you will run into ambiguity and Access will revert to mm/dd/yyyy. The best format is four digit year, month, day (yyyy/mm/dd or yyyy-mm-dd) which is not ambiguous in any locale.

Comment: COMMAS!!! `update stackoverflow set status = 'idiot' where user = 'kolin'`

Comment: amazingly i've just done this same thing on another stored procedure. DOH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
UpdateTransaction 1, '17470312', #30/10/2012#, 93
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15222/How-to-Use-Stored-Procedures-in-VB6

Comment: Can't believe i missed the commas out. unbelievable.